# In this function, what is the real meaning of the " * " operator?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os
import base64
import socket
import subprocess

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
PADDING='#'

def _pad(data, pad_with=PADDING):
    return data + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(data) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
```

I understand that the character "#" is used to pad the block but I can't understand the meaning of the "*", used normally for multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, you can multiply a string by an integer to repeat the string that many times. E.g.

```
'a' * 4
```

produces

```
'aaaa'
```

Any class can overload an operator like `*` by [implementing specially-named methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

Answer (score 1):

The `* PADDING` means exactly that (*times* `PADDING`).

`* PADDING` is *add  `(BLOCK_SIZE - len(data) % BLOCK_SIZE)` times `#` to the end of `data`*.
It calculates the amount of *padding* needed for the specific data based on its size and the `BLOCK_SIZE` and adds extra `#` which is the `PADDING`.

The calculation is the `BLOCK_SIZE` minus the length of the `data` passed to the function, all this modulo the `BLOCK_SIZE`.

Example:

```
>>> BLOCK_SIZE = 20
>>> data = 'this is my data'
>>> PADDING = '#'
>>> data + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(data) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
'this is my data#####'
```

The calculation performed is:

```
data + (20 - 15%20)*PADDING = data + (20 - 15)*PADDING = data + 5*PADDING = data + '#####'
```

Answer (score 1):

str type gets the * operator:

```
'#' * 10 = '##########'
```

because `__mul__()`  method is defined in the str class definition:

```
'#'.__mul__(10) = '##########'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: You're attempting to explain how the `*` operator maps to the `str` class' `__mul__` method, which is correct, but doesn't answer the OP's question as to *what effect it actually has*. My answer was simple, yes, but it explains exactly what the OP wanted to know.

Comment: Now that you've edited your answer to include an example, it answers the question, and I've removed my down-vote.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> a= '#'
>>> a* 12
'############'
>>>
```

Comment: ok sorry, I was typing this answer meanwhile so many answers came.

Comment: That tends to happen with questions like this one.

Comment: Yes right, also he is newbie. My intention was seeing this simple code he will  try in his python console. And next time before asking a question he would try something in his console first.

Comment: But your answer included no text. It is not obvious to a newbie that `>>>` implies the use of thr Python console.